# how to generate evenly distributed n-permutation from range 0 to m (m<n)

Tags: c++, algorithm

repeating of a number is allowed but the probability is limited

for example:
giving a number sequence 0-8,i want to generate a 25 number random sequence,the max repeate time of a digit is 3.

Comment: Could you be more clear and provide some examples .?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the [pseudo-random number functionality in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)?

Comment: You're going to have to be much more precise with the specification. Also, I suggest you ask this on the mathematics website. What I think you're asking is difficult to get right statistically.

Comment: finally i use this method: first make a random sequence and push_back x times,where x=(int)ceil(n/(float)m),then random_shuffle

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand you need something like this (Reworked according to comment below):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;

vector<int> Generate(const vector<int> & numbers, int generateN, int maxRepeatN)
{
    vector<int> longList(numbers.size() * maxRepeatN);

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < maxRepeatN; j++)
            longList[i * maxRepeatN + j] = numbers[i];

    vector<int> result(generateN);

    for(int i = 0; i < generateN; i++)
    {
        int id = rand() % longList.size();
        result[i] = longList[id];
        longList.erase(longList.begin() + id);
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    vector<int> numbers = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

    vector<int> result = Generate(numbers, 25, 3);

    for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
        cout << result[i] << " ";          

    return 0;
}
```

Idea of algorithm is that you create long list of all possible digits to get (it guarantees that you won't get more than a max digits of one type). Then you get digits one by one from it (removing digits after getting from long list guarantees distribution).
*This code is for example only and such use of std::vector is not optimal at all.

Comment: This algorithm doesn't produce uniform samples, though. In the case where we want to draw 4 numbers, each either 0 or 1, with at most 2 repetitions, there should be 6 equally likely outputs: 0011, 0101, 0110, 1100, 1010, and 1001. An initial 0 should be followed by a 1 two-thirds of the time. However, your algorithm will follow an initial 0 with a 1 only half of the time.

Comment: Ah. I understand. It's not difficult to rewrite it to suit your condition.

Comment: Er, I'm afraid I don't see how. :)

Comment: Help yourself. ^) However, it should be mention that it only works when we know what number of digits we want to get exactly. If we must get it one by one and stop anytime there is need in other algorithm.

Comment: Okay! There's a bug in the `distribute` function, which might repeat a value too many times. It would be better to perform a [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle). Still, even with that fix, there's a subtle correlation. Suppose that we draw 3 numbers from 3 possibilities with at most 2 repetitions. Then the probability that all 3 numbers are different should be 1/4. But with your algorithm, that probability is 2/9.

Comment: I fixed bug, thank you. Now I'll try to understand what's wrong with the distribution. Hmm, it seems I'm already using Fisher–Yates shuffle.

Comment: As I understand the problem with distribution is that I imply restriction that repititions are directly proportional to numbers we draw (as I understand author of question). And if repetitions should be adjusted independantly, yes, there should be other way.

Answer (score -1):

One relatively foolproof method is rejection sampling. Generate 25 numbers independently. If any number appears more than 3 times, throw them all away and try again. This method has poor worst-case performance, but it's so simple that you won't have to worry that you've accidentally introduced unwanted correlations.